# Does it cost to convert pointer to value in c++?

Tags: c++

I am learning c++.
I learned when I should use 'pass by pointer' or 'pass by const reference' at google style guide.
 It says

(1) if any members changes in a function, the value should be passed by pointer.

(2) if any members does not changed in a function, the value should be passed by const reference.

I wonder that when I have a pointer of a instance and any members will not change in a new function whether I need to make the function with pass by const reference to keep google style guide or not. If so, I need to convert the pointer to real value by '*pointer'. I am caring of the cost of conversion from pointer to real value but honestly I don't know whether it has cost or not. Please tell me how to do it in this situation.

This situation happens when I use visitor pattern. I need to use 'this' pointer but the members does not change in a function. I don't know whether there are any benefit or cost to keep google style guide in this situation.

In case, I copy sample code below. It is a part of visitor pattern. And it has two functions made with pass by pointer and pass by const reference.

```
#include <iostream>

class ClassA;

class VisitorInterface {
public:
    virtual ~VisitorInterface() = default;
    virtual void operator() (ClassA* obj) const = 0;
    virtual void operator() (const ClassA& obj) const = 0;
};

class VisitorsHostInterface {  // = visitor's host
public:
    virtual ~VisitorsHostInterface() = default;
    virtual void accept(VisitorInterface* v) = 0;
    virtual void accept(const VisitorInterface& v) = 0;
};

class VisitorsHost : public VisitorsHostInterface {
public:
    virtual ~VisitorsHost();
    void accept(VisitorInterface* v) override {};
    void accept(const VisitorInterface& v) override {};
};

class ClassA : public VisitorsHostInterface {
public:
    void print() const { std::cout << "ClassA value_ = " << value_ << std::endl; }
    void accept(VisitorInterface* v) override {
        (*v)(this);
    };
    void accept(const VisitorInterface& v) override {
        v(*this);
    };
private:
    int value_=11;
};

class Visitor : public VisitorInterface {
public:
    virtual ~Visitor() = default;
    void operator() (ClassA* obj) const override {
        if (obj) {
            obj->print();
        }
    }
    void operator() (const ClassA& obj) const override {
        obj.print();
    }

};
```

Comment: Don't follow the Google style guide. Follow the C++ Core Guidelines instead. https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines

Comment: @Brian: Why reject the Google style guide? Perhaps the OP is being told to follow it explicitly.

Comment: @Brian : thank you for telling me another guideline. Three persons vote your comment. So it seems the guidance you suggest seems to be more standard. I will read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, no

You have two signatures

```
void accept(VisitorInterface* v) override {};
void accept(const VisitorInterface& v) override {};
```

They both expect a reference (or pointer and reference if you want to be exact), so you are not actually converting this to an object and in both cases you will just pass the address of `this` to each of the accept functions

However if you had

```
void accept(const VisitorInterface v) override {};
```

You could have invoked a copy-constructor which can be expensive, depending on what it does.

Comment: I don't think we can construct an abstract class?

Comment: @Danh -- not sure I follow -- are you asking a new question or criticizing the answer?

Comment: criticize this answer

Comment: The question was "Does it cost to convert pointer to value in c++?", and the code compiles fine for me -- there may be other problems with the OP code, but not trying to address those.

Comment: Did you try to compile the code in your last statement?

Comment: Yep -- added "int main(int c, char**a) { ClassA xx;}" and ran "$ g++  -std=c++11  yy.cc;  ./a.out" -- don't see the issue.

Comment: @Soren : thank you for answering. Yes, my question is ' *pointer ' takes cost or not. And your answer is no, if the function does not copy the whole data of the instance. So maybe I can use const reference in this case. Thank you again. And if anyone feel uncomfortable to my question because it was not clear, I am sorry I am a beginner and I am not native English speaker.

Comment: @mora Be careful, the last point isn't correct. An abstract class can't be the parameter of a function

Comment: @Soren I guess you're using an Apple MacBook! gcc in MacOS is just a link to clang, clang has its infamous bug with this matter. Abstract class can't be passed by value to a function. See this quote: http://eel.is/c++draft/class.abstract#3 This bug is fixed particularly in clang trunk

Comment: @Danh -- $ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)
on Fedora 23 Linux

Comment: @Soren gcc 5.3.0 http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/u98kDHtMsRLAXPcF Anyway, it's accepted by some compiler doesn't mean it's correct, it's incorrect by the quote I quoted above

Comment: @Danh  -- I took your version on rextester and compared it to the code posted by the OP -- it is not the same, you have an extra virtual interface which is what causing you the problem -- my code is the same as the OP and compiles just fine

Comment: @Soren My first comment is about your last statement `void accept(const VisitorInterface v) override {};` This is illegal!

Comment: Can you go back to take a look at my 3rd comment, it meant the 5th comment in this conversation.

Comment: :-)    ....    dude, that was to illustrate the difference between copy by reference and copy by value to answer the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

First, for the question you are asking, these is no difference between passing in `*this` and `this` from a performance standpoint when you have `Thing *` and `const Thing &` as the alternative overloads to select between.

But, your code has other confusions and problems. You have several different dimensions of visitation going on here, and I think you're confusing to orthogonal cases. Here are the cases as I see them:

1. You have a visitor that will be unchanged as it visits and the thing being visited will also not be changed.
2. You have a visitor that will be changed as it visits and the thing being visited will not be changed.
3. You have a visitor that will be unchanged as it visits and the thing being visited will be changed.
4. You have a visitor that will be changed as it visits and the thing being visited will also be changed.

I think you are confusing the cases of the thing being visited being changed, and the visitor changing as it visits things. If you weren't, you'd have four different `accept` methods all over the place instead of two, or the accept methods in the `VisitorHostInterface` and the `VisitorInterface` would have their `const` qualifiers in different spots.

Comment: Thank you for clear answer. I am not sure I follow you exactly but I used two different accept functions only to avoid compile error; error of same name functions with same parameters. I should have mention it. It is coincident but two accept functions with pointer and const reference might be too similar to my original question and it might introduce your warning. Anyway thank you again.

Comment: @mora - If you want the pointer and const reference version to say the same thing about the modifiability of what's being passed in, then make the signature for the pointer version `something * const`. Then you are saying that what's being pointed at can't be modified. Getting your `const`s right shouldn't be guesswork, because if it is, you aren't really understanding what you're doing. And `const` correctness is too important to just wing like that.

Comment: Yes you are right. I should have use 'some_type * const' in this case. I only focused on conversion from pointer and value. Thank you again.